# Android https form submission?

Tags: java, android, http, https

Hi I'm having a lot of trouble submitting a simple form, I have searched around and it appears quite a few people have had the same problem but I haven't found an answer.

Here's my code so far:

```
public void postData(TextView txtResult, String user, String pass) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

     HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.mymeteor.ie");
     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userpass", pass));
     post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

     String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
     txtResult.setText(responseText);

}
```

The above code will simply return the original page,

can anybody help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that URL supports logging in via post that way? It looks to me like the login form sends the post data to this URL: `https://www.mymeteor.ie/go/mymeteor-login-manager`

I would also suspect you should be using some sort of API instead of just posting data to their login form, remotely.

Comment: I'm not sure at all I will try that url, unfortunately they don't provide any api thanks.